# First steps after acquiring a new MacBook Pro (w.r.t ensuring optimal battery life)?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, battery

I just unboxed a new MBP 13.3 inch i5. I wanted to know what is the best way to start using it, so as to ensure optimal battery life i.e.

- Should I charge it to full capacity, before even booting it ?
- Should I start using it out of the box on AC ?
- Also, going forward, what must I do to ensure that the battery lasts longer, and the average capacity doesn't go down with the years ?

While I appreciate individual experiences/suggestions, I'd really like links to articles/reviews from respectable websites that could authenticate the information - there are simply too many opinions out there :).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing. Use it and charge it when it gets low. There aren't any "tricks" to ensuring a healthy battery anymore, but Apple does recommend the following:

> Be sure to fully charge your portable when you plug it in for the
>   first time, and then run Software Update to ensure you have the latest
>   software.

The new Apple notebooks (2009 and up) monitor the health of your battery and charge it accordingly, so there is very little maintenance required anymore. In fact, they no longer even require [battery calibrations](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1490). All new Apple notebook batteries are pre-calibrated and ready to use.

As for usage trends to ensure longevity, that too is all handled by the OS and you can consult [Apple's battery article](http://www.apple.com/batteries/) for more details.

To be honest, storing the battery in the fridge or freezer, running it down and then charging it, pulling it out when using AC, or all the other myriad of "tricks" you'll read about are snake oil. Batteries have a limited life-span, and they start to deplete as soon as they are manufactured. That is the nature of batteries. Using them only exacerbates this phenomenon. There is no magic wand to turn back the hand of time.

In closing, Apple has some tips on [how to maintain your notebook's battery](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html). Just follow their recommendations, and enjoy your new computer.

Comment: They do recommend [fully charging it when you first plug it in](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html), and to periodically use it unplugged "to keep the electrons in it moving occasionally."

Comment: "Energy: The Energy Saver control panel offers several settings that determine power levels for your PowerBook." O rly Apple?

Answer (score 1):

I've been suggested to finish all the battery without pluging the charger when unboxing my Macbook Pro. Then Recharge it for about 14 hours then start using. But the light on the plug has already turned to green after 4 hours recharging first time. I won't wait for 14 hours of course. There is s.thing that I suggest not to use a Lithium-Polymer Battery while it's on charge. And it's recommended trying to finish all the energy before recharging again.